# Electric potential significance

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, potential-energy

What is the physical significance of electric potential? I know that over dx length of an electric field it varies but let us assume the field to be uniform, how exactly does the potential still change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [electric potential at center of uniform electric field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43357/electric-potential-at-center-of-uniform-electric-field)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electric potential is zero but non zero electric field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110610/electric-potential-is-zero-but-non-zero-electric-field).    You leave a lot of room for interpretation in your question.  If the suggested links don't help, please clarify the question.  And welcome to PSE.  For future reference:  please search this site to see if your question has been addressed.  There are many professional physicists here, and we want to make the best use of their (my) time.